# Tomcat bases application acceess

Tags: tomcat

I have Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M10 on windows 10 installed.
I am able to access the application on local machine. Also I can assess the same from other's desktop. But I am not able to assess them from laptops within in same network. I tried setting firewalls and server.xml   -->

but no success. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a TCP inbound settings you may need to enable in your system. Since other desktops can access your tomcat, it could be enabled by default.

Check the following

1. do "ping " in command prompt from laptop to check whether both systems are in same network
2. try accessing with ip address like "http://yourIpAddress:portNo"

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have verified that both the systems are in same network. Aslo "http://yourIpAddress:portNo" is working fine. Not sure what is the issue.